# How can I filter the 2016 Presidential Election data to include entries with N.A. while fulfilling other conditions?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I'm using the dplyr package to filter the 2016 US presidential election data (in `dslabs`), so that it fulfills the following conditions:

1. state == U.S.
2. end date after 2016-10-31
3. Grade above B, but include entries with N.A. in grade

This is the code that I have right now:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dslabs)
polls <- polls_us_election_2016 %>% filter(state == "U.S." & enddate >= "2016-10-31"&
                                       grade %in% c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+") | 
                                         is.na(grade))
```

But this code ends up including entries with N.A. in grade that do not fulfill the first 2 conditions. How can I ensure that only entries that fulfill the first 2 conditions are included?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare the dates with date objects and not strings and keep condition for `grade` separate.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(dslabs)

polls_us_election_2016 %>%
  filter(state == "U.S." & enddate > ymd('2016-10-31') & 
        (grade %in% c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+") | is.na(grade)))
```

Or in base R

```
subset(polls_us_election_2016, state == "U.S." & enddate > as.Date('2016-10-31') & 
         (grade %in% c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+") | is.na(grade)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dslabs)
library(lubridate)
as.data.table(polls_us_election_2016)[state ==  "U.S." & 
    enddate > ymd('2016-10-31') &
     (grade %chin%  c("A+", "A", "A-", "B+") | is.na(grade))]
```